# How I can decide to overwrite create() method on generic views class or serializer class

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm a newbie with Django rest framework and according to what I had learned. `create()` method in generic views use to generate the response while `create()` in serializer class use to save instances of model in the database. Is it correct?

The problem is I have a `Tag` model has the `name` field has to be unique. So I decided to overwrite the `create()` method in generic views to check if the `name` of `Tag` model already exists or not. Does it make sense or I should overwrite `create()` method on serializer class instead

Below is my code for that

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs): 
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    if self.check_tag(request.data) == False: 
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        return Response(
            data=serializer.data,
            status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        )
    return Response(
        data={'name': 'tag with this name already exists.'},
        status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
    )
```

P/s: I can't add `unique` attribute for `name` field in the model because some other reasons

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, You can overwrite create method in serializer class.

```
class MySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fileds = (...)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # You can customize this method
        return validated_data
```

Comment: so which one is makes more sense in my case? overwrite ```create()``` method in ```serializer class``` or ```generic views```

Comment: It depends on your program. If you want to customize your create process, then use create method, and if not you can use generic view. But you can write create method and also use CreateAPIView in generics.